# Best way to remove item in a v-treeview?

Tags: vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

i need to remove an item from a v-treeview component. What is the best way to do this ? Does it require a reload of the tree ?

The component : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview

Thanks for answers,
S.

Comment: Before we can help, please show some code so that we may see what you have attempted.

Answer (score -1):

Check Vue basics - List rendering
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html